# What is the best way avoid reload the jsp page?

Tags: liferay

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSRQ.png)Here is my jsp code

```
<portlet:renderURL var="rssSearchResult">
<portlet:param name="<%=CMD.ACTION%>"
    value="<%=RenderKeys.FIND_CONTENT_SEARCH%>" />
    <%-- <portlet:param name="categoryId" value="<%=String.valueOf(category.getCategoryId())%>"/> --%>
```

```
<div id="category-content" class="span8">
    <aui:form render="<%=rssSearchResult %>">
        <aui:input placeholder="Please Enter RSS Feed Title Here"
            name="search" label="" id="searchTitle" type="text"
            style="width:300px;" />
        <aui:button type="button"  name="search" id="searchTitle" value="submit" class="Find_content_search"
            onclick="javascript:mynav('<%=rssSearchResult%>');addinMoveableBar();"></aui:button>
    </aui:form>
```

*************Here is my java source code************

```
@RenderMapping(params=CMD.ACTION+StringPool.EQUAL+RenderKeys.FIND_CONTENT_SEARCH)
public void rssSearchResult(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) {

    String searchValue= ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "search");
    DynamicQuery SearchaQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(
            AssetEntry.class, PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
    SearchaQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("title").eq(searchValue));
    try {
        List<AssetEntry> assentries=AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(SearchaQuery);
        List<AssetCategory> assetcategory=null;
        for(AssetEntry assetentry:assentries){
             assetcategory= AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getAssetEntryAssetCategories(assetentry.getEntryId(), -1, -1);
        }

        renderRequest.setAttribute("AssetCategory", assetcategory);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("AssetEntries", assentries);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*************main.js***************

```
function mynav(navurl){
    ajaxindicatorstart("Processing Please Wait");
    loadPage(navurl);
    history.pushState({}, '', navurl);

}
```

I have a search text box with submit button if i search title of category it has to be display without reloading the page....

Comment: Great. So what isn't working? Be specific

Comment: am not getting the sub category list if i click on submit button..page was not reloading thats fine...but searching string title was not getting

Comment: It seems to me like a Liferay development. If true, then please add `liferay` tag, so the question reaches right people. You could also remove `javascript`, `jsp` and `java` tags, as they are too unspecific for your question.

Comment: How can I solve the problem that the data is not changed when the page load?

Comment: Could you add in any browser console  or server error logs,if any,or any screenshot of your search in action.

Comment: I have added screen shot please cliack on image description

Comment: Finally i got the solution for this....Ty for ur valueable time